# How to solve requirement of "On/Off publishing" for 'read article' action

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph, built-in

Now facebook require to have these options when you want to use bulit-in actions like READ.

"A clear way for users to control the publishing of their actions back to Open Graph. In the example News app below, a clear "On/Off" switch is provided that applies to all future Read actions within the app. When a user toggles the switch to "Off", this prevents the app from publishing Read actions from that point on. Toggling the switch back to "On" reenables the publishing. "

"A clear way for users to remove articles that were just shared through your app. In the example below, a user can easily remove a recent article that was shared as a result of a Read action that was published by the app."

sample pictures are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read under title "Publish Awareness"

How to create easy button to stop sharing and to remove shared articles? The best one will

I was searching for solution for one week without results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has two parts to it, one is storing the user preference and the other is share/unshare option to be given on the article page. The first part of the question is simple and can be achieved by simply having a small database table with minimum of two columns (for simplicity sake), userid (a varchar or long int) and share (a bool or a bit). Give an option to the user to toggle this share bit by giving an on/off button which changes the share value from 1 to 0 (true to false) and vice versa for a specified userid. Now before taking a social action (like read), check for this share bit in database for the logged facebook user and perform actions accordingly.

Now to answer the second part of your question, you may use the Facebook JavaScript SDK to make api calls to news.read action and provide a callback to store the returned id of the shared article. Use the same id to then provide option of unshare for the user. Assuming that you have jQuery included in your page, something like below should work (I wrote and tested it in a jiffy, should work in most cases)

> **Include the below script in your page**

```
//set this at page load or from authResponse object
var fbDataObj = {
    user_id : <some user id>,
    access_token: <some access token>
};

//set currentPostFBUrl to your article url
var currentPostFBUrl = "http://www.yourpageurl.com";

var publishPost = function (articleLink, callback) {
    FB.api(
        '/' + fbDataObj.user_id + '/news.reads',
        'post',
        { article: articleLink,
          access_token: fbDataObj.access_token },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              //alert('Error occured');
              if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback({text: "error", id: ""});
              }
           } else {
              //alert('Share was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
              if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback({text: "success", id: response.id});
              }
           }
        });
};

var deletePost = function (postId, callback) {
    FB.api(
        postId,
        'delete',
        { access_token: fbDataObj.access_token },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              //alert('Error occured');
              if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback({text: "error", id: ""});
              }
           } else {
              //alert('Unshare was successful!');
              if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback({text: "success", id: ""});
              }
           }
        });
};

var publishOrDeleteArticle = function (btn_obj) {
    var btn_name = btn_obj.attr("name");
    if (isNaN(parseInt(btn_name, 10))) {
        publishPost(currentPostFBUrl, function(status){
            if (status.text === "success") {
                btn_obj.attr("name", status.id);
                btn_obj.text("Unshare");
            }
        });
    }
    else {                  
        deletePost(btn_name, function(status){
            if (status.text === "success") {
                btn_obj.attr("name", "share");
                btn_obj.text("Share")
            }
        });
    }
};
```

> **Now in your page do something like this**
>
> **Edit:**
>   (Also set currentPostFBUrl to your article url like below)
>   ***var currentPostFBUrl = "http://www.yourpageurl.com";***

```
//within script tag
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_share").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        publishOrDeleteArticle($(this));
    });
});
//your actual share/unshare button
<a id="btn_share" name="share" href="#">Share</a>
```

*On the final note I have written one wrapper js class for one of the recent facebook application that I was working on. With this you can read/unread an article with just one line of code. There are other WordPress wrappers inside as well but that can be left alone in this case, at the simplest you may use the object as below after providing the initial configuration and init (check the attached code below). There might be a few bugs in the code and the methods might not be complete and extensive because I'm still working on it but for the time being it should solve the purpose. The below wrapper methods can also be used in the above mentioned code for clarity. Feel free to use/modify the code, give feedback and comments and also reply back in case any issues are identified.*

```
/*!
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Utility Library for Facebook Application
 * Contains wrapper methods for WordPress JSON API (named WPJsonApi)
 * and for Facebook Javascript SDK (named FBJsWrapper)
 * Dependency : jQuery, Facebook JavaScript SDK
 * Author : Emad Alam
 * Date: Thu Jun 07 21:11:03 2012 +0530
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:
 * Including this script adds a global object called FBAppUtil to the window object.
 * You may initialize the object with init method, providing init time configurations.
 * Once FBAppUtil object is initted, you get two sub-ojects, WPJsonApi & FBJsWrapper.
 * These two objects can be initted individually or while initing the main FBAppUtil.
 * Both the objects have a buffer that stores the last fetched data and responses.
 * Methods are provided to access these buffers individually.
 * Once the sub-objects are configured, their methods can be called from their references.
 *
 * Example Usage:
 *          //main object init. config can be given at this time
 *          FBAppUtil.init();
 *
 *          var wpJsonApiConfig = {
 *                  apiUrl : "http://www.example.com/wordpress/api",
 *                  permalinkEnabled : true,
 *                  crossDomain : true
 *          };
 *          FBAppUtil.WPJsonApi.init(wpJsonApiConfig);
 *          
 *          // now you may use all the methods of FBAppUtil.WPJsonApi 
 *          FBAppUtil.WPJsonApi.getRecentPosts(someParams, someCallback);
 *          FBAppUtil.WPJsonApi.getPost(someIdOrSlug, someCallback);
 *          var data = FBAppUtil.WPJsonApi.lastFetched();
 *          var response = FBAppUtil.WPJsonApi.lastResponse();
 *
 *          // other facebook related scripts and sdks initializations
 *          // at this point you should be having the FB object initialized
 *          // you may pass the authResponse object to init the FBJsWrapper or
 *          // populate one of your own to pass it to the FBJsWrapper.init(authResponse)
 *
 *          var fbJsWrapperConfig = {
 *                  userID : <logged in userId>,
 *                  accessToken : <user's accessToken>,
 *                  signedRequest : <from authResponse object>,
 *                  expiresIn : <from authResponse object>
 *              };
 *          FBAppUtil.FBJsWrapper.init(fbJsWrapperConfig);
 *          
 *          // now you may use all the methods of FBAppUtil.FBJsWrapper
 *          FBAppUtil.FBJsWrapper.sendAppRequest("some message", someCallback);
 *          FBAppUtil.FBJsWrapper.share(someArticleUrl, someCallback);
 *          FBAppUtil.FBJsWrapper.unshare(someId, someCallback);
 *          var fbdata = FBAppUtil.FBJsWrapper.dataFromLastCall();
 *          var fbresponse = FBAppUtil.FBJsWrapper.responseFromLastCall();
 */

(function (window) {

    /** Local helper Buffer Class - Start **/
    var LocalBuffer = function (size) {

        //enforce 'new' - object creation pattern
        if (!(this instanceof LocalBuffer)) {
            return new LocalBuffer(size);
        }

        //private variables
        var _buffer = {
            data        : [], //data fetched from the last successfull call
            response    : [] //response from the last call
        },
            _size = (function (size){
                        var n = parseInt(size || 10, 10);
                        return isNaN(n) ? 10 : n;
                    }(size)); //default buffer size

        var _pushToBuffer = function (name, data) {
            if (typeof _buffer[name][_size-1] !== 'undefined') {
                _buffer[name].shift(); //remove the first element in case the buffer is full
            }
            _buffer[name].push(data);
        };

        var _readFromBuffer = function (name) {
            var len = _buffer[name].length;
            return len === 0 ? {} : _buffer[name][len-1]; //read the last inserted without popping
        };

        var _getDataFromBuffer = function () {
            return _readFromBuffer("data");
        };

        var _getResponseFromBuffer = function () {
            return _readFromBuffer("response");
        };

        //expose methods
        this.pushToBuffer           =   _pushToBuffer,
        this.readFromBuffer         =   _readFromBuffer,
        this.getDataFromBuffer      =   _getDataFromBuffer,
        this.getResponseFromBuffer  =   _getResponseFromBuffer
    };  
    /** Local helper Buffer Class - End **/

    /** WordPress JSON API Plugin wrapper - Start **/
    var WPJsonApi;
    (function () {
        var instance;
        WPJsonApi = function (config) {
            if (!(this instanceof WPJsonApi)) {
                return new WPJsonApi(config);
            }
            if (instance) {
                return instance;
            }
            instance = this;

            //config variables
            var apiUrl, //complete url for the api
                cross_domain, //jsonp cross domain calls
                permalink_enabled, //whether permalink enabled
                templates, //TODO: templating system
                buffer_size; //size of the buffer

            //private variables
            var _buffer; //the LocalBuffer object

            //form the final api url string for the json call
            var _getControllerUrl = function (controller_name) {
                var url = apiUrl; //base url
                if (!permalink_enabled) {
                    url += "/?json=" + controller_name;
                    if (cross_domain) {
                        url += "&callback=?";
                    }
                } else {
                    url += "/" + controller_name;
                    if (cross_domain) {
                        url += "/?callback=?";
                    }
                }
                return url;
            };

            //fetch posts using the jQuery getJSON
            //push data and response to buffer
            //on successfull fetch, return array of post objects to the callback
            var _getRecentPosts = function (paramObj, callback) {
                var url = _getControllerUrl("get_recent_posts"); //base url for the specified controller
                if (typeof paramObj === 'function') {
                    callback = paramObj; //no parameters provided only callback
                    paramObj = {};
                }
                paramObj = paramObj || {};
                $.getJSON(url, paramObj, function(data) {
                        if (data.status === "ok") {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status  : "ok",
                                    success : "Successfully fetched the post for the specified id/slug."
                                }
                            );
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("data", data);
                            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                                callback(data.posts);
                            }
                        } else if (data.status === "error") {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status: "error",
                                    error : data.error
                                }
                            );
                        } else {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status: "error",
                                    error : "Unknown error!"
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                );
            };

            //fetch post by it's id or slug using the jQuery getJSON
            //push data and response to buffer
            //on successfull fetch, return the post object to the callback
            var _getPost = function (paramObj, callback) {
                var url = _getControllerUrl("get_post"), //base url for the specified controller
                    id  = parseInt(paramObj, 10); //assume the parameter to be id

                paramObj = paramObj || {};

                if (typeof paramObj !== 'object') {
                    if (typeof paramObj === 'number' || !isNaN(id)) {
                        paramObj = {id : id};
                    } else if (typeof paramObj === 'string') {
                        paramObj = {slug : paramObj};
                    }
                } 

                if (isNaN(parseInt(paramObj.id, 10)) && !paramObj.slug) {
                    throw {
                                status: "error",
                                error : "Provide a valid id or slug to get a post."
                            };
                }

                //TODO: Avoid server hit by searching and returning the post
                //      from the local buffer for the specified id/slug
                $.getJSON(url, paramObj, function(data) {
                        if (data.status === "ok") {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status  : "ok",
                                    success : "Successfully fetched the post for the specified id/slug."
                                }
                            );
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("data", data);
                            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                                callback(data.post);
                            }
                        } else if (data.status === "error") {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status: "error",
                                    error : data.error
                                }
                            );
                        } else {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status: "error",
                                    error : "Unknown error!"
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                );
            };

            //initialize the object and add methods to it
            var _init  = function (config) {
                if (typeof config === 'undefined') {
                    throw {
                        status: "error",
                        error : "Provide a valid configuration object to initialize WPJsonApi."
                    };
                }
                apiUrl = config.apiUrl || "/api", //assume base url relative to current page
                cross_domain = config.crossDomain || false, //jsonp cross domain calls
                permalink_enabled = config.permalinkEnabled || true, //assume permalink enabled
                templates = config.templates || {}, //TODO: templating mechanisms
                buffer_size = config.bufferSize || 10, //assume buffer size to be 10
                _buffer = new LocalBuffer(buffer_size); //new buffer object

                //expose the methods and variables
                this.getRecentPosts = _getRecentPosts; //method for fetching recent posts
                this.getPost        = _getPost; //method to fetch the post by id or slug
                this.lastFetched    = _buffer.getDataFromBuffer; //last fetched data from the buffer
                this.lastResponse   = _buffer.getResponseFromBuffer; //response from the last roundtrip to server
            };

            //init the object if config is provided while creating
            if (typeof config !== 'undefined') {
                _init(config);
            }

            //expose init
            this.init = _init;
        };
    }());
    /** WordPress JSON API Plugin wrapper - End **/

    /** FB JavaScript SDK wrapper - Start **/
    var FBJsWrapper;
    (function () {
        var instance;
        FBJsWrapper = function (config) {
            if (!(this instanceof FBJsWrapper)) {
                return new FBJsWrapper(config);
            }
            if (instance) {
                return instance;
            }
            instance = this;

            //config variables
            var access_token, //user access token
            expires_in, //time to expire
            signed_request, //the signed request object
            user_id; //user id of the current connected user

            //private variables
            var _buffer, //the LocalBuffer object
                _token_valid = true; //assume the access token to be valid

            var _isTokenValid = function () {
                //TODO: Implement the method to check for invalid access tokens or
                //      invalid calls to FB APIs
                return _token_valid;
            };

            var _read = function (article, callback) {
                //TODO: Avoid repeated code, make a generic function

                var paramObj = {}; //start with an empty parameter

                paramObj.article = article; //add article to the parameter object

                //if token is invalid, no further calls are possible, so return
                if (!_isTokenValid()) {
                    //TODO: Provide a better way of handling this
                    throw {
                        status: "error",
                        error : "Provide a valid configuration object to initialize FBJsWrapper."
                    };
                }

                if (!(!access_token || 0 === access_token.length)) {
                    paramObj.access_token = access_token; //access token not empty, add it to the parameter object
                }

                //TODO: Make a generic function to handle this call
                FB.api(
                    '/' + user_id + '/news.reads',
                    'post',
                    paramObj,
                    function(response) {
                        var i,
                            message, // response error message
                            exists = false, //assume the words don't exist in the message           
                            probable_words = [  "session has expired",
                                                "session has been invalidated",
                                                "session is invalid",
                                                "has not authorized" ]; //list of words that may denote an invalid token

                        //no response, return
                        if (!response) {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status  : "error",
                                    error   : "No response returned by the server!"
                                }
                            );
                            return;
                        }

                        //some error
                        if (response.error) {
                            message = response.error.message.toLowerCase(); //case insensetive match
                            for (i in probable_words) {
                                if (message.indexOf(probable_words[i]) > -1) {
                                    exists = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (exists) {
                                _token_valid = false; //denotes invalid token
                            }
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status  : "error",
                                    error   : exists ? "Invalid access token!" : response.error.message
                                }
                            );
                        } else {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status  : "ok",
                                    success : "Successfully read the specified article."
                                }
                            );
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("data", response);
                            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                                callback(response.id);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            };

            var _unread = function (articleId, callback) {
                //TODO: Avoid repeated code, make a generic function

                var paramObj = {}; //start with an empty parameter

                //if token is invalid, no further calls are possible, so return
                if (!_isTokenValid()) {
                    //TODO: Provide a better way of handling this
                    throw {
                        status: "error",
                        error : "Provide a valid configuration object to initialize FBJsWrapper."
                    };
                }

                if (!(!access_token || 0 === access_token.length)) {
                    paramObj.access_token = access_token; //access token not empty, add it to the parameter object
                }

                //TODO: Make a generic function to handle this call
                FB.api(
                    articleId,
                    'delete',
                    paramObj,
                    function(response) {
                        var i,
                            message, // response error message
                            exists = false, //assume the words don't exist in the message           
                            probable_words = [  "session has expired",
                                                "session has been invalidated",
                                                "session is invalid",
                                                "has not authorized" ]; //list of words that may denote an invalid token

                        //no response, return
                        if (!response) {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status  : "error",
                                    error   : "No response returned by the server!"
                                }
                            );
                            return;
                        }

                        //some error
                        if (response.error) {
                            message = response.error.message.toLowerCase();//case insensetive match
                            for (i in probable_words) {
                                if (message.indexOf(probable_words[i]) > -1) {
                                    exists = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (exists) {
                                _token_valid = false; //denotes invalid token
                            }
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status  : "error",
                                    error   : exists ? "Invalid access token!" : response.error.message
                                }
                            );
                        } else {
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                                {
                                    status  : "ok",
                                    success : "Successfully unread the specified article."
                                }
                            );
                            _buffer.pushToBuffer("data", response);
                            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                                callback();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            };

            var _sendAppRequest = function (message, callback) {
                var paramObj = {}; //start with an empty parameter

                if (typeof message === 'function') { //no message only callback provided
                    callback = message;
                    message = 'Invite friends to this app.';
                }

                paramObj.method = 'apprequests';
                paramObj.message = message.toString();
                if (!(!access_token || 0 === access_token.length)) {
                    paramObj.access_token = access_token; //access token not empty, add it to the parameter object
                    paramObj.display = 'iframe'; //access token provided, iframe can be used
                } else {
                    paramObj.display = 'popup'; //no access token present, use popup dialog
                }

                FB.ui(paramObj, function (request, to) {
                    //TODO: Handle the error conditions
                    _buffer.pushToBuffer("response",
                        {
                            status  : "ok",
                            success : "Successfully sent the app request."
                        }
                    );
                    _buffer.pushToBuffer("data", { request: request, to: to });
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback(request, to);
                    }               
                });
            };

            var _init  = function (config) {
                if (typeof config === 'undefined') {
                    throw {
                        status: "error",
                        error : "Provide a valid configuration object to initialize FBJsWrapper."
                    };
                }
                access_token = config.accessToken || "", //assume a blank access token, will try to call FB.api without it
                expires_in = config.expiresIn || 0, //jsonp cross domain calls
                signed_request = config.signedRequest || {}, //signed request parameter
                user_id = config.userID || 'me', //assume 'me' (for a user it's user_id but for pages and apps it might be something else)
                buffer_size = config.bufferSize || 10, //default buffer size
                _buffer = new LocalBuffer(buffer_size); //local buffer object

                //expose the methods and variables
                this.sendAppRequest         = _sendAppRequest; //method for sending the app request from a dialog
                this.share                  = _read; //method to read an article, news.read
                this.unshare                = _unread //method to unread a previously read article
                this.dataFromLastCall       = _buffer.getDataFromBuffer; //last fetched data from the buffer
                this.responseFromLastCall   = _buffer.getResponseFromBuffer; //response from the last roundtrip to server
            };

            //init the object if config is provided while creating
            if (typeof config !== 'undefined') {
                _init(config);
            }

            //expose init
            this.init = _init;
        };
    }());
    /** FB JavaScript SDK wrapper - End **/

    /** The main Utility Class - Start **/
    var FBAppUtil;
    (function () {
        var instance;
        FBAppUtil = function () {
            if (!(this instanceof FBAppUtil)) {
                return new FBAppUtil();
            }
            if (instance) {
                return instance;
            }
            instance = this;

            var _init  = function (config) {
                if (typeof config !== 'undefined'){ 
                    if (typeof config.WPJsonApi !== 'undefined') {                  
                        this.WPJsonApi = new WPJsonApi(config.WPJsonApi); //WPJsonApi configuration provided while init
                    } else {
                        this.WPJsonApi = new WPJsonApi();
                    }
                    if (typeof config.FBJsWrapper !== 'undefined') {                    
                        this.FBJsWrapper = new FBJsWrapper(config.FBJsWrapper); //FBJsWrapper configuration provided while init
                    } else {
                        this.FBJsWrapper = new FBJsWrapper();
                    }
                } else {
                    this.WPJsonApi = new WPJsonApi();
                    this.FBJsWrapper = new FBJsWrapper();
                }
            };

            //expose the methods and variables
            this.init = _init;
        };
    })();
    /** The main Utility Class - End **/

    // Expose the Utility to the global object
    window.FBAppUtil = new FBAppUtil();
})(window);
```

> ***FBAppUtil.FBJsWrapper.share(someArticleUrl, someCallback);***
>   ***FBAppUtil.FBJsWrapper.unshare(someId, someCallback);***

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to use it properly.
First of all, I don't know how to get: user_id &  access_token
Because I was posting other actions without these vars.
--
How to use "publishPost" if it is not a function?
--
Another problem: "Share" button does nothing.
-
My old post code:
   function postAgree()
   {
    FB.api('/me/app-name:agree_with?article=<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>',
        'post');
   }

And I was using it by onclick="postAgree()"
(it gets link by Wordpress's function)
-
Maybe it helps: I have installed Facebook PHP SDK to get user's profile photo etc.

Comment: And some more informations:
- I have a jQuery installed

I saw a great 'publishing system' here [link](http://wiadomosci.onet.pl/ciekawostki/kosmiczny-teleskop-hubblea-sfotografowal-boga,1,5096454,wiadomosc.html)

After login in the middle of the page, you will see your facebook panel on the right. You can stop publishing your actions or delete them one by one etc (you can use google translate, it is polish language).

Link to  whole javascript of this panel (maybe it will help) [link](http://lib.onet.pl/fb/info,loader.js?t=22346513)

Best regards

Comment: Hi @user1340908 : Sorry for delayed response. 
The code above was indicative, you don't actually need user_id and access_token if you include the Facebook's JavaScript SDK with proper callbacks, it itself will set the user_id to current logged in user and access_token to proper values, as you had mentioned calling the api without these. And to answer the next part of your question, I had been doing exactly the same, i.e bind that share functionality to the click event of the button. the only thing I missed to include there was the JavaScript variable **currentPostFBUrl** setting to article url

Answer (score 1):

With articles, facebook recommend that you place the trigger on a 'readmore' or some other kind of 'next page' button/link so that there is a very high probability that the user is actually reading the article.

To achieve this, you could either;

1. place a small form in/on every article, with a radio button/ckeckbox
   asking do you want to publish this (Yes/No)  --  OR
2. add a section to your user preferences on your site with the same
   type of form as in 1. Then you could take this a bit further, giving
   them the option to set a preference for each section, category or
   page of your site.

Either way, however you decide to invoke the action (readmore or next page etc.), that needs to submit the form, check whether the answer is yes/no (publish or not) then publish the action accordingly.

Using session variables might be an option too! It would be pretty neat to offer users the ability to publish/not publish actions for their current session. This could be handled in the same form being presented to the user at the start of each session and even give them a 3rd option, 'ask me everytime'.

As far as deleting an existing action is concerned, this can be done by getting the instance of the action and running the delete command in a similar way to that of creation. As I said, this depends on how you're triggering - CURL, js api etc... Check the FB dev docs for the method you're using.

Hope this helps!

Gez

Comment: @user1340908 did you get this sorted?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried also solution on the top of page by eMAD but without success.

Answer (score 0):

On/Off publishing is not related to **Facebook Graph API**, you have to implement this on your side. there should be a flag viz is_publish related to user table. If user give permission by click on the user On/Off button than you can publish the action, and one thing more action can be published only if user stay on article page for at-least 10 seconds and for this you can do

setTimeout('readArticle()', 10000);

Hope this helps!